# Django Tutorial - error message doesn't display

Tags: python, django

I am working my way through the Django tutorial. Currently at [Part 4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial04/), where if you vote without selecting a choice, the page should reload with an error message displayed above the poll. However, when I do so, the page reloads, but no error message is being displayed. The development server is not showing any errors, btw.

Here is the template code:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

And here is a snippet of the view.py function for the vote:

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question}, {'error_message' : "You didn't select a choice."})
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question_id,)))
```

Any help as to why the error message is not showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the context dictionary in return rather that two different dicts. So your view would be like.

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        context = {
         'question': question, 
         'error_message' : "You didn't select a choice.",
        }
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', context)
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question_id,)))
```

Comment: Ah, I see what I did there, thanks! All working now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly surprised you aren't getting an error message from `render`.

You're passing your context data to the template as two dictionaries, but Django doesn't work like that. You only want one dictionary with all your context data provided.

```py
# This line...
return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question}, {'error_message' : "You didn't select a choice."})

# ...should be written like this instead.
return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question, 'error_message' : "You didn't select a choice."})
```

Comment: Thank you, I see the mistake I did!